# How can I repeat this boost (push)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I dont understand how I can make this shotgun jumps in my version of Unity: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FUkdz8jYt3w

How does this work?

Im using "First Person Controller" that looks like capsule
There are images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIkjz.jpg

This is for old version of Unity 4.5.5. I've tried RigidBody, but nothing happened. I've tried `Transform`, but again, no result.

First Person Controller:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class run : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public float speed = 6.0F;
    public float jumpSpeed = 8.0F;
    public float gravity = 20.0F;
    private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;
    public Transform character;
    public int CharacterForce = 5000;
    public int time = 1;

    void Update() 
    {
        CharacterController controller = 
        GetComponent<CharacterController>();

        if (controller.isGrounded) 
        {
            moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis ("Vertical"));
            moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);
            moveDirection *= speed;

            if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))
                moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;
        }

        moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        controller.Move (moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) 
        {
            Transform BulletInstance = (Transform)Instantiate(character, GameObject.Find("CameraRSP").transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

            BulletInstance.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(transform.forward * CharacterForce);
        }
    }
}
```

"Grenade" code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class grenade : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Transform GrenadeF;
    public int force = 500;
    public float radius;

    void Start() 
    {
        Collider[] col = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, radius);
        foreach (Collider c in col) 
        {
            c.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddExplosionForce(force, transform.position, radius);
        }
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmosSelected() 
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.blue;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(transform.position, radius);
    }
}
```

When I used `Transform` I expected that this would work in ANY direction, but it worked in only one.
When I used `RigidBody` I expected that this would WORK, but my capsule didnt even moved.

Comment: What are you doing to spawn `GameObject`s with the `grenade` script?

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the optional [`upwardsModifier`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddExplosionForce.html) parameter of

```
AddExplosionForce(float explosionForce, Vector3 explosionPosition, float explosionRadius, float upwardsModifier = 0.0f, ForceMode mode = ForceMode.Force));
```

(The API for Unity 4 is no longer available but I guess it should have been the same there)

> Adjustment to the apparent position of the explosion to make it seem to lift objects.

and

> Using this parameter, you can make the explosion appear to throw objects up into the air, which can give a more dramatic effect rather than a simple outward force. Force can be applied only to an active rigidbody.

By default it is `0` so if you don't pass it there won't be any upwards force.

---

As you can see in the example from the [API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddExplosionForce.html)

```
Vector3 explosionPos = transform.position;
Collider[] colliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(explosionPos, radius);
foreach (Collider hit in colliders)
{
    Rigidbody rb = hit.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    //                                                        |
    //                                                        v
    if (rb) rb.AddExplosionForce(power, explosionPos, radius, 3.0f);
}
```

they passed e.g. `3.0f` as `upwardsModifier`. This makes the explosion

> appear to be centred 3.0 units below its actual position for purposes of calculating the force direction (ie, the centre and the radius of effect are not modified).

---

*Note: Typed on smartphone so no warrenty but I hope the idea gets clear*

Comment: sorry, i forgot another one collider how can i add another one?

Comment: well, i got another idea, but when i press LMB, im getting trough the plane